# Within babel traverse how do I throw an error with specific information about that line?

Tags: syntax-error, babeljs, traversal

I am looking to throw an error when traversing over parsed code using babel / babylon.

I thought `path.buildCodeFrameError` would work, [but it does not work in traverse](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8617).

```
  babelTraverse(nodes, {
    ImportDeclaration: (path) => { 
      modules.push(path.node.source.value)
    },
    CallExpression: (path) => {
      const module = getCallExpression(path.node, 'require')
      const variable = getVariable(path.container)
      if (VALID_LIBS.includes(module) && !variable) {
        throw path.buildCodeFrameError(`"${module} must have a variable assigment`)
      }
    }
  })
```